# TBXML Parser to parse an RSS Feed

Tags: iphone, tbxml

I am trying to parse this feed: http://missing.amberalertnederland.nl/nl/index.rss with the TBXMLParser. For that purpose im using this code:

```
- (void)loadRecords:(NSString *)records {
NSString *someXML = @"http://missing.amberalertnederland.nl/nl/index.rss";
TBXML *tbxml = [[TBXML tbxmlWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:someXML]] retain];

records = [NSMutableArray array];
[records retain];

if (tbxml.rootXMLElement)
    [self traverseElement:tbxml.rootXMLElement];
[tbxml release];
}

- (void) traverseElement:(TBXMLElement *)element {
do {
    if (element->firstChild) 
        [self traverseElement:element->firstChild];

    if ([[TBXML elementName:element] isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
        TBXMLElement *title = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"title" parentElement:element];
        TBXMLElement *link = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"link" parentElement:element];
        TBXMLElement *description = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"description" parentElement:element];

        [records addObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                            [TBXML textForElement:title],
                            [TBXML textForElement:link],
                            [TBXML textForElement:description],nil]];  
    }
} while ((element = element->nextSibling));  


NSLog(@"%@", records);
}
```

However the records array only returns (null) values.

Any guide on how to use TBXML ( i thought i did correctly ) would also be welcome.

Comment: Consider just revising your existing question. Once edited, it will appear on the front page again.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used TBXML, i use [`SMXMLDocument`](https://github.com/nfarina/xmldocument)

And here is the method I use for parsing RSS:

```
- (NSArray *) arrayNewsItemsFromDocument:(SMXMLDocument *)document {
    SMXMLElement *channel = [document.root childNamed:@"channel"];

    NSArray *itemArray = [channel childrenNamed:@"item"];

    NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[itemArray count]];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    //Mon, 11 Jul 2011 00:00:00 +0200
    [dateFormatter setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"EN"] autorelease]];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZZ"];

    for (SMXMLElement *item in itemArray) {     
        News *news = [[News alloc] init];
        news.title = [item childNamed:@"title"].value;

        NSString *text  = [item childNamed:@"encoded"].value;

        news.text =  [self stringFromHTMLString:text];
        news.articleUrl = [item childNamed:@"link"].value;
        NSString *dateString = [item childNamed:@"pubDate"].value;

        NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
        news.date = date;

        [mutableArray addObject:news];
        [news release], news = nil;
    }

    [dateFormatter release], dateFormatter = nil;

    NSArray *newsArray = [[mutableArray copy] autorelease];

    [mutableArray release], mutableArray = nil;

    return newsArray;
}
```

Comment: SMXMLDocument simply uses NSXMLParser, i want to use TBXMLParser.